# NEO4J algo.unionFind java.rmi.UnmarshalException

Tags: java, neo4j

I have thirty million nodes and thirty million relationships.
I want to use `algo.unionFind()` to find all subgraphs, but i'm getting the following error.

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ call algo.unionFind('CUST1','NONE', {write:true, partitionProperty:"partition"}) YIELD nodes,setCount,loadMillis,computeMillis,writeMillis;

java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:236)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:161)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:227)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.interpretLine(Unknown Source)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.AbstractClient.evaluate(AbstractClient.java:147)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.AbstractClient.evaluate(AbstractClient.java:131)
    at org.neo4j.shell.impl.AbstractClient.grabPrompt(AbstractClient.java:99)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.grabPromptOrJustExecuteCommand(StartClient.java:412)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.startRemote(StartClient.java:359)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.start(StartClient.java:229)
    at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.main(StartClient.java:147)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:265)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:222)
    ... 11 more
```